# How to save and retrieve Date with timezone in java and SQLserver

Tags: java, sql-server, timezone, localdate

I am new to backend and stuck with a problem.
My application has an input field which saves the date - A user can save the date in the database and another user can retrieve the date but is in a different time zone.
I don't know how to save it and send the response after converting it to retrieving ends time zone.

Comment: Can you show us the code that reads and writes the values from/to the database.

Comment: Try read this article. There is basically 3 timezones. The sql server's timezone, the java application's timezone, and client's timezone. https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/practical-example-handling-time-zone-conversion-java-rest-darshana

Comment: Do you really mean a date, or do you mean a date with time-of-day? What is the exact data type of the column? What is the exact data type (class) in your Java code, And, just to confirm, are you using Microsoft SQL Server? Your question is vague as currently written; I suggest a rewrite with specifics.